# robospice usecase: external rest-service returns null

Tags: java, android, spring, robospice

I have found following code in [this](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/blob/release/robospice-sample-spring-android/src/com/octo/android/robospice/sample/springandroid/MainActivity.java) sample of [Spring Android module](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Spring-Android-module) :

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_LAST_REQUEST_CACHE_KEY)) {
        lastRequestCacheKey = savedInstanceState
            .getString(KEY_LAST_REQUEST_CACHE_KEY);
        spiceManager.addListenerIfPending(FollowerList.class,
            lastRequestCacheKey, new ListFollowersRequestListener());
        spiceManager.getFromCache(FollowerList.class,
            lastRequestCacheKey, DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE,
            new ListFollowersRequestListener());
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Override
public void onRequestSuccess(FollowerList listFollowers) {

    // listFollowers could be null just if contentManager.getFromCache(...)
    // doesn't return anything.
    if (listFollowers == null) {
        return;
    }

    followersAdapter.clear();
```

So, what do you suggest to do if external rest-service will return `null` as successfull result oneday?

Comment: Result of this would be an empty ListView displayed to a user. Exactly as it suppose to be. If server says "here you go, client, i give you null records" there's not much the client can do about it.